# How to make state immutable in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, immutability

I am looking for the best way to make my handleSwitch + setState function immutable. The code I have currently works but is mutable and I am unsure how to make it immutable everything I have tried either doesn't work or gives me a syntax error.

This is my state being initialised

```
this.state = {
      contacts: [],
      filteredContacts: [],
      selected: [],
      contactsSelection: {},
      loading: false,
    };
```

I have a simple `<Switch />` comp which triggers the below when a user toggles the switch.

```
handleSwitch = async (contact, added) => {
    if (added) {
      console.log('added', { contact, added });
      return this.setState(prevState => ({
        contactsSelection: {
          ...prevState.contactsSelection,
          [contact.id]: contact,
        },
      }));
    }

    console.log('removed', { contact, added });
    // const { contactsSelection } = this.state;
    return this.setState(prevState => {
      const existingSelection = { ...prevState.contactsSelection };
      delete existingSelection[contact.id]; // <-- make immutable
      return { contactsSelection: existingSelection };
    });
  };
```

Comment: You are not mutating in removed because you make a shallow copy first and then remove the key from that copy.

Comment: On second thought it's an object didn't see that, and your code is already returning a new object so it is immutable. Do you mean you want to do it in a more functional idiomatic way, it will be a bit ugly and less efficient (e.g. convert to an array + reduce to new object)

Answer (score 0):

just to clarify: your code is fine by now, it does not mutate state directly but mutates copy.

but if you'd like having that in different way, here is a pattern:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
      const { [contact.id]: unusedVariable, ...restContacts } =
          prevState.contactsSelection;
      return { contactsSelection: restContacts };
})
```

or with destructuring:

```
this.setState(
  ({ contactsSelection: {[contact.id]: unused, ...filteredContact} })) => 
      ({ contactsSelection: filteredContacts })
);
```

Anyway unfortunately there is no way to avoid introducing `unusedVariable` while destructuring. So it will need you to suppress ESLint warning "variable ... is not used".

To me, your way handling that is better readable.

Comment: ahh, thanks thats really useful, I couldn't figure out how to use rest, { val, ...otherVal  }